# Изменение дубликатов в таблице (Update Set)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица zip такого вида: код-город, где `^^^^` — пробелы после имени города.

```
zip  | city
--------------------
06542 | Brest^^^^
06542 | Brest^^^
06542 | Brest^^
06541 | Adler^^^^
06541 | Adler^^^
```

Тут совпадение кода и имени города независимо от количества пробелов после имени является дубликатом.
Надо во всех таких дубликатах пробелы перенести в начало имени чтобы получилось так:

```
zip  | city
--------------------
06542 | ^^^^Brest
06542 | ^^^Brest
06542 | ^^Brest
06541 | ^^^^Adler
06541 | ^^^Adler
```

Пробовал вариант:

```
UPDATE zip SET city = 
    SUBSTRING(zip.city from '[\\s]+$') ||
    SUBSTRING(zip.city from '^.+[^\\s]') 
FROM (SELECT zip.zip, zip.city from zip INNER JOIN (
    SELECT zip, SUBSTRING(zip.city from '^.+[^\\s]') AS city1 FROM zip
    GROUP BY zip, city1
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) A ON A.zip=zip.zip AND
  A.city1=SUBSTRING(zip.city from '^.+[^\\s]'))as i
```

`regexp '^.+[^\\s]'` — любое количество символов с начала строки до пробела
`regexp '[\\s]+$'`  — пробелы на конце строки

`SELECT` работает, с `UPDATE` проблемы.

Понял в чем проблема, осталось придумать как решить: Update Set пытается менять весь набор данных в таблице zip, игнорируя условие после FROM, то есть меняет все записи в таблице, соответстевнно сабстринги возвращают нал на некоторых записях, у которых в конце нет пробелов... Осталось придумать как сделать так, чтобы апдейт действовал только на рекордсет, который возвращает FROM

Comment: Какие проблемы возникают? Ошибка или работает не так? Что на выходе?

Comment: zip и city это UNIQUE Constraint, но поле zip не уникальный id, поэтому, думаю, возникает неоднозначность при апдейте, ошибка такая:null value in column "city" violates not-null constraint

Answer (score 2):

решение найдено:

```
 
UPDATE zip SETcity=repeat('',length(arbitrary.city)length(rtrim(arbitrary.city)))||rtrim(arbitrary.city) 
FROM (
SELECT zip.zipid, zip.zip, zip.city from zip INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  zip, SUBSTRING(zip.city from '^.+\S') AS city1 FROM zip
    GROUP BY  zip, city1
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) subtable ON subtable.zip=zip.zip AND subtable.city1=SUBSTRING(zip.city from '^.+\S')) as arbitrary
WHERE zip.zipid = arbitrary.zipid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update zip set city= repeat(' ',length(city)-length(rtrim(city)))||rtrim(city)
where rtrim(city) in(select rtrim(city) from zip group by rtrim(city) having count(*)>1);
```

Comment: хороший запрос, но минус в том что он не выбирает дубликаты, а делает замену всех записей, хотя тоже вариант в принципе, спасибо!

Comment: Ну, я думал, вы WHERE сами напишете. Или нет?

Comment: я тоже думал :) но с моей выборкой в данном случае выходит ошибка, хотя сама по себе она работает, та которая в примере

Comment: Если так, то я дописал WHERE в ответе.

Comment: Благодарю! Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

У вас регулярка не верна. Попробуйте city присваивать это

```
SUBSTRING('Brest    ' from '\s+$')|| SUBSTRING('Brest    ' from '^.+\S')
```

Comment: спасибо, исправил, но по факту одинаково: на апдейте: ERROR: null value in column "city" violates not-null constraint

Comment: @Heineken, ваша регулярка возвращала null, поэтому  возникала ошибка

Comment: не могла она нул возвращать :) на селекте же все отлично работает :) ну в любом случае я исправил все регулярки и результат тот же остался :(((((

Comment: SELECT zip.zip, zip.city from zip INNER JOIN (
    SELECT zip, SUBSTRING(zip.city from '^.+\\S') AS city1 FROM zip
    GROUP BY zip, city1
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) A ON A.zip=zip.zip AND A.city1=SUBSTRING(zip.city from '^.+\\S');
Этот запрос работает, как только на него навешивается сверху апдейт то вылет с ошибкой